# Dynamically creating multiple Facebook like buttons using php

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to add multiple like buttons to one page (for different articles) - I have looked on the net and it states to point the url to a new page that contains "the meta data you want to display".

I created a simple php page that automatically populates the meta based on the news article. However everytime I run it on the Facebook debugger it doesn't seem to pick these up?

When I query the page I can see the meta has fully customised but it doesn't reflect on Facebook.

Has anyone got any ideas why this may be happening and if so maybe a solution? I see a number of companies doing this at the moment just not sure how, surely I don't need to create a new static page for every single like button?

thanks steve

Answer (score 0):

I use the follow code, you need to implement inside a foreach, and change `data-href`

```
<div id="fb-root" style="display:none"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="80" data-show-faces="false" data-href="<?php echo $someUrl; ?>"></div>
```

Comment: I have done as you have done above my problem is with my other page.